# Spring data JPA - Exclude ID column from one entity parameter

Tags: java, jpa, primary-key, one-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities :

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Engine engine;
}
```

and the other one :

```
@Entity
public class Engine {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String value1;

    @Column
    private String value2;
}
```

In my jpaRepositoy interface, i would like to do :

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    public Car findByEngine(Engine engine);
}
```

But this method doesn't return my entity stored, because I created my Engine doing :

```
Engine engine = new Engine("someValue", "someValue");
```

without setting engine's id which is stored in database.

So I would like to know if it is possible exclude a column like id ?
If no, is the only way to do this is :

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.engine.value1 = :value1 and c.engine.value2 = :value2")
findByEngine(@Param("value1") String value1, @Param("value2") String value2)
```

?

**Related question** : If I have OneToMany relationship instead of OneToOne, like

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Engine> engines;
}
```

How can I do this request to have something like (still without id column) :

```
public Car findByEngines(List<Engine> engines);
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: this `@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.value1 = :value1 and c.value2 = :value2")` is not correct jpql query for your scenario, You do not have value1 and value2 in `Car` entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.value1 = :value1 and c.value2 = :value2")` is not correct jpql query for your scenario, You do not have `value1` and `value2` in `Car` entity.

Correct one would be:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.engine.value1 = :value1 and c.engine.value2 = :value2").
```

You can try this method Name, I think that will work:

```
findByEngineValue1AndEngineValue2(String value1, String value2)
```

but for list  one, i do not think you can make it up with just method name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made the mistake writing the query but I was obviously thinking at the good one (c.engine.value1...). the method findByEngineValue1AndEngineValue2 works, thank you. For list one, what's the way to do in JPQL please ?

Comment: @Matiou, For the list I do not think you can do it, I am not sure 100% tho